# Seeking help regarding installing and using mips-gcc cross compiler to generate custom ASM

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, mips, cross-compiling

I'm trying to generate assembly for my custom ISA which is similar to MIPS. I have read about using mips-gcc cross compiler to generate a MIPS asm from a C program and then translate it to an asm required by us, but then i couldn't get a clear picture of it. Someone please explain me the procedure and how this can be achieved.

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@dwelch Has done a pretty extensive job of answering your question but I thought I would add just a bit because I have a MIPS cross-compiler installed and I thought it would be worth showing you how to generate assembly directly from C source.

Here is test.c:

```
int main()
{
    return -7;
}
```

To generate assembly with my cross-compiler I would use: `mips-elf-gcc-3.4.6 test.c -S` where `-S` is the flag to generate assembly.

This creates a file called test.s that looks like:

```
    .file   1 "test.c"
    .text
    .align  2
    .globl  main
    .ent    main
main:
    .frame  $fp,8,$31       # vars= 0, regs= 1/0, args= 0, gp= 0
    .mask   0x40000000,-8
    .fmask  0x00000000,0
    addiu   $sp,$sp,-8
    sw  $fp,0($sp)
    move    $fp,$sp
    li  $2,-7           # 0xfffffffffffffff9
    move    $sp,$fp
    lw  $fp,0($sp)
    addiu   $sp,$sp,8
    j   $31
    .end    main
```

For an extra bonus we can ratchet up the optimization on the compiler to get more efficient assembly using `mips-elf-gcc-3.4.6 test.c -S -O3`. This looks like:

```
    .file   1 "test.c"
    .set    nobopt
    .text
    .align  2
    .globl  main
    .ent    main
main:
    .frame  $sp,0,$31       # vars= 0, regs= 0/0, args= 0, gp= 0
    .mask   0x00000000,0
    .fmask  0x00000000,0
    .set    noreorder
    .set    nomacro
    j   $31
    li  $2,-7           # 0xfffffffffffffff9
    .set    macro
    .set    reorder

    .end    main
```

Comment: Thanks Konrad !!
I got a better picture after reading your answer. Hopefully I get it to work for my custom ISA :)

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are talking about a binary translation.

Take this code for example

```
unsigned int fun ( unsigned int a, unsigned int b, unsigned int c )
{
    return((a+b)&c);
}
```

Lets say I want to use a mips C compiler because I dont have a compiler for my processor (in this case I am going to use ARM simply for demonstration purposes, we do of course have ARM compilers).  Also MIPS to ARM is not a one to one thing, but for this simple example it will work just fine.  Because ARM does not use a delay slot, we ask gcc not to do that and we compile this

```
mips-elf-gcc -O2 -c -fno-delayed-branch fun.c  -o fun.o
mips-elf-objdump -D fun.o
```

I am cheating of course, you will want to link to some address, I am taking a short cut and disassembling the object.  Your translator starts by reading the MIPS binary you may or may not wish to pre-scan through the instructions starting at the entry point, in execution order following all the paths and making a note of all the branch destinations.  Also isolate which bytes are instructions and assume ones that are not are data.  BUT, sine mips is fixed instruction length (well not really, there is a 16 bit version that can be mixed in) you can also take the approach of starting at the beginning and disassembling all of it, you will end up disassembling data and creating extra work.

So I let gnu disassemble this for me for this example

```
00000000 <fun>:
   0:   00851021    addu    v0,a0,a1
   4:   00461024    and v0,v0,a2
   8:   03e00008    jr  ra
   c:   00000000    nop
```

Taking one instruction at a time your translation tool would pick apart the instruction (disassemble it)

```
   0:   00851021    addu    v0,a0,a1

00000000100001010001000000100001 0x00851021
000000 00100 00101 00010 00000 100001
000000 sssss ttttt ddddd 00000 100001 addu rd,rs,rt
          r4    r5    r2
```

ending up with

```
addu r2 = r4 + r5
```

so we translate that directly to the arm equivalent

```
add r2,r4,r5
```

Second instruction

```
   4:   00461024    and v0,v0,a2

00000000010001100001000000100100
000000 00010 00110 00010 00000 100100
000000 sssss ttttt ddddd 00000 100100 and rd,rs,rt
       r2    r6    r2


and r2 = r2 & r6
```

arm

```
and r2,r2,r6
```

third instruction

```
   8:   03e00008    jr  ra

000000 11111 000000000000000 001000 
000000 sssss 000000000000000 001000  jr rs
       r31

jr r31 or return from function
```

arm

```
bx lr
```

fourth instruction

```
          c:    00000000    nop
```

arm

```
nop
```

So for those four mips instructions we have a direct static binary translation to arm

```
add r2,r4,r5
and r2,r2,r6    
bx lr
nop
```

Now you can do one of two things you can put a label on each instruction and then if/when
there is a branch you can branch that label, or for cleanliness you can preview all the code
and look for branch destinations and only label those.  Build your label using the mips address, makes it easier to keep track.

```
L00000000: add r2,r4,r5
L00000004: and r2,r2,r6    
L00000008: bx lr
L0000000C: nop
```

In this case I have created arm assembly language which I would feed into

```
arm-none-eabi-as fun.s -o fun.o
arm-none-eabi-objdump -D fun.o

fun.o:     file format elf32-littlearm

Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <L00000000>:
   0:   e0842005    add r2, r4, r5
00000004 <L00000004>:
   4:   e0022006    and r2, r2, r6
00000008 <L00000008>:
   8:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
0000000c <L0000000C>:
   c:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)
```

We dont need to care about the label named fun, the address is how the processor works and how it is encoded into instructions, etc so you can use the label with an address as I have above and it will work.  Well of course if there are any computed addresses used for branch
destinations, or perhaps even loads and stores then you have to deal with that in your
translator.

Now if your new instruction set is very very similar to the mips you are using to compile with then you dont need to go to assembly you simply translate from machine code to machine code making the subtle changes in the one to one translation, if it is not a one to one machine code translation then you will need to create a pseudo assembler, that allows you to deal with labels and one to one or many mips instructions to your instructions.

since I am this far along, a related tangent if you are trying to use static binary translation to say convert from MIPS to ARM for real, you SHOULD NOT use assembly language on the target side.  Use C or your favorite high level language.  This makes it much more portable to any instruction set (if you are doing this exercise once you may want to not have to do it a second time for another instruction set).  Most importantly though you are allowing the C compilers optimizer for the target deal with removing your dead code, a direct translation when you start to deal with processor flags and such things creates a large amount of dead code that you have to deal with.

So instead of

```
L00000000: add r2,r4,r5
L00000004: and r2,r2,r6
L00000008: bx lr
L0000000C: nop
```

If my target has an optimizing C compiler but it is not a mips target and I only have a mips binary that I am translating I dont have the original source then translate to something like

```
...
unsigned int r2;
...
unsigned int r3;
unsigned int r4;
unsigned int r5;
unsigned int r6;
...
unsigned int PC;

switch(PC)
{
...


case L00000000: 
L00000000: 
   r2=r4+r5;
   r2=r2&r6;
   PC=0x00000008;
   break;
...
}
```

With some code wrapped around this switch to manage entry and exit of function calls.  Naturally, there is a lot more work that I have not described.

I know it is bad form to use links, but Graham Toal wrote a Static Binary Translation HOWTO which you can google search and hopefully find http://www.gtoal.com/sbt/ and hopefully it is still there.

Of course if your instruction set is fairly close to mips then why dont you just modify binutils to have it encode your instructions or modify gcc to have it generate the variation on your assembly language?